# Erro no pacote Java Resources em projeto Maven

Tags: java-ee, maven

Criei um projeto `Maven` com apenas uma página `xhtml` só pra teste, porém fica dando esse erro no pacote.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que seria esse erro?

Comment: Parece estar usando eclipse olha no `Markers` se apresenta algum erro especifico, caso não funcione da um clean e validate no projeto.

Comment: Dei um Clean e saiu o erro, obrigado.

Comment: De que maneira essa pergunta pode ser melhorada, @Downvoter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para corrigir este erro, siga os passos abaixo:

```
 Eclipse > Project > Clean
```

O Eclipse possui um marcador de erros `Markers`, é interessante sempre olhar ele nesses casos.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, não resolveu Eclipse > Project > Clean;

O que resolveu meu problema foi clicar com o botão direito do mouse sobre o projeto, na opção Maven cliquei em Update Project...

Há também a possibilidade de usar as teclas de atalho Alt+F5